# Family of Analytic Functions on an Open Set

Tags: complex-analysis

Actually I was having a look at this problem [Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657980/uniform-convergence-of-a-sequence-of-functions) and was wondering if the result still holds hood if the boundedness condition on the domain is dropped.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple counterexample is easy: Take $f(z) = z^2$ on $D = \mathbb{C}$; then $f(0) = 0$, $f^{\prime}(0) = 0$, and $f$ is certainly analytic as a map from $\mathbb{C}$ to itself.  Yet clearly the $n$th iterate of $f$ at $z = 2$ will be $2^{(2^n)}$, which clearly diverges, and in general for $\vert z \vert > 1$, $F_n(z) = f \circ f \circ \dotsb \circ f(z)$ will diverge in general.

The issue is that $f: D \to D$ was what forced a very strong boundedness when $D$ was bounded (in particular, why you couldn't just use $z \to z^2$ on a disk of radius $> 1$ to get an easy counterexample in the original problem) and you don't get that when $D$ is unbounded, at least not immediately.

I wonder if the formula would work on a strange domain in $\mathbb{C}$; it is not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: I think that it will work on a simply connected proper subset of C as then we can use the Riemann Mapping Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

If $D \subset \mathbb C$ is any domain such that $\mathbb C \backslash D$ contains at least two points, then by Montel's theorem the analytic functions from $D \to D$ form a normal family.  If $f$ is such a function, and $f(p) = p$ and $f'(p) = 0$  for some $p \in D$, then the iterates $F_n$ of $f$ have a subsequence converging uniformly on compact sets to an analytic function $g$, 
and it is easy to show that $g$ is constant.